# Using for...in syntax to add event listeners causes some sort of scope issue?

Tags: javascript, closures

I wanted to use the pattern below to add event listeners to a group of buttons. In the code below I'm expecting a button click on `a` to print `a` to the console, but it prints `c`. Same for `b`. It looks like there's some kind of scope issue, and it seems like some sort of closure would solve the problem, but I can't figure out how to get it right.

```js
var buttons = {
  a: document.getElementById('a'),
  b: document.getElementById('b'),
  c: document.getElementById('c')
}

for (var key in buttons) {
  buttons[key].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(key);
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="a">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
```

Comment: By the time the buttons have been clicked, the loop has already finished. It will always show the last value unless you create a separate scope for each iteration (a closure).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is completely a duplicate question as mentioned, I read the other question/answers and there are subtle differences.